# Python - Iterating over / counting spaces and punctuation

Tags: python, for-loop

I cannot understand why the below code is not updating/incrementing the "spaces" or "sentences" variable - but it is recognising "letters"

Any suggestions would be immense! Thank you so much!!

```
from cs50 import get_string

text = get_string("text:  ")
i = 0
letters = 0
spaces = 0
sentences = 0;

for element in text:
    if text[i] != '.' and text[i] != '?' and text[i] != '!' and text[i] != '"' and text[i] != ',' and text[i] != '-' and text[i] != ':' and text[i] != ';' and text[i] != ' ':
        letters += 1

for element in text:
    if text[i] == " ":
        spaces += 1

for element in text:
    if text[i] == '.' or text[i] == '?' or text[i] == '!':
        sentences += 1

words = spaces +1

L = float(letters/words *100)
S = float(sentences/words *100)
A = float(0.0588*L)
B = float(A - 0.296*S)
C = float(B - 15.8)
index = int(C)

if index < 1:
    print("Before Grade 1")
elif index >= 16:
        print("Grade 16+")
else:
    print("Grade %i\n", index)

print(L,S,A,B,C,index, i, letters, spaces, sentences)
```

Comment: You are repeated looking at the first letter of the text and are never incrementing i.   Your code should be `if element != '.' and element != '?' .....`   Replace `text[i]` with `element` everywhere.

Why do you have three separate loops rather than one loop performing all three tests?

Comment: thank you so much Frank, this is fantastic! You've helped me address my approach to this problem and coding in general. Much obliged :-)